# Is there an example of an HTML page that matches current specifications?

Tags: html

Whenever I (rarely) start creating an HTML document, I go through the current HTML specification and create a skeleton that, as far as I know, adheres to the current standards.

Is there any website / service that generates these skeletons?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html><title>Example</title>` is a valid skeleton. Not a very useful one, but a valid one.

Comment: You're missing a closing tag. :)

Comment: I'm not missing anything that is required.

Comment: Ah - my mistake then. That's partially my point though. As someone who rarely works with HTML, it would be nice to have a useful template generator.

Comment: i think html5 boilerplate may be what you are looking for. for some it's overkill, for others it's perfect. either way, good starting point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The skeleton you need is super simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Body of the page
  </body>
</html>
```

Anything beyond that is up to the specific needs of your site.

Comment: @JakeGould — What problems will the HTML 5 Doctype cause for IE 6 and 7? I've had a look through the document you link to and can't see anything like that. (OTOH, it is a large document so I might have missed something).

Comment: Jake – that's patently false. The whole point of the html5 doctype is to ensure it does work in IE6 and 7! It's the smallest possible one that doesn't trigger quirks mode.

Comment: @JakeGould Exactly what Rich Bradshaw said.  The HTML 5 doctype works perfectly for IE6 & 7 (or that is, they have the same inconsistencies with html5 doctype as they would with any of the XHTML transitional doctypes).  I'm not sure where you're getting your information... That document even says you should be using the HTML 5 doctype...

Answer (score 0):

Website? Not that I know of. But I use [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html?utm_source=thedeck&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=bbedit) on a Mac and it does a great job of creating all kinds of basic HTML & XHTML starting documents. Just opened it up & it created a nice default XHTML document without any hassle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 10.5" />
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why xhtml 1.0 transitional?  Let's just stick with the HTML 5 doctype:  `<!DOCTYPE html>` and not worry about any of that other nonsense ;)

Comment: ..and?  These days what's the point in using anything else ;)  Also, let's agree not to point people to w3schools.  http://w3fools.com

Comment: Did you read that page?  "I am not recommending any of the XHTML doctypes, because serving XHTML as text/html is considered harmful. If you choose to use an XHTML doctype anyway, please note that the XML declaration makes IE 6 (but not IE 7!) trigger the Quirks mode."  I use html5 doctype exclusively and have yet to have IE6 or IE7 act any more out-of-whack than they would have if I used an older doctype.

Comment: XHTML requires you to jump through Appendix C to make it work in all but very recent versions of IE. It's far more trouble then it is worth.